# angular directive not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to include directives in my application, but even basic directives aren't rendering. what am i doing wrong?

angularloader.js:

```
var main = angular.module('ngMain', [])
.directive('myScrollable', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
};
});
```

My HTML:

```
<html ng-app dir="auto">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@Model.Title</title>
<script src="/Scripts/Libs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Custom/angularloader.js"></script>
</head>
<body dir="auto">
<my-scrollable></my-scrollable>
</body>
</html>
```

tried also using  tag or attribute ..

Answer (score 2):

you should use *module name* in `ng-app="moduleName"`

like:

```
<html ng-app="ngMain" dir="auto">
```

if you assign angular module in a variable then use that variable like bellow:

```
var main = angular.module('ngMain', []);
main.directive('myScrollable', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<h3>Hello Worlds!!</h3>'
};
});
```

[Working PLUNKER Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/HHNkkK3shiZsWRiJjZF7?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. Iv'e added the module name but it still remains:
    <my-scrollable></my-scrollable>
Iv'e tried also linking the script from plunker but it didn't help..

Comment: what is your angular version ? try 1.4.x

Comment: I'm using latest 1.4.4. i've tried also the script from plunkr 1.4.3 but the same. I'm using chrome 44.0.2403.157 m.

Answer (score 0):

You have define your module but forget to use in html with ng-app= "you module Name". One extra thing you don't need to declare a variable main your code will work without that also.

```
angular
.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myDir', function{
  your code
});
```